Why did Moses flee to Midian? (Exodus 2:15)
Exodus 2:15:

When Pharaoh heard of it, he sought to kill Moses. But Moses fled from
Pharaoh and stayed in the land of Midian. And he sat down by a well.

Moses fled to Midian after Pharaoh sought to kill him. Moses had killed an Egyptian who was beating a Hebrew (Exodus 2:11-12). When Pharaoh learned of this, he sought to execute Moses. Fearing for his life, Moses chose to escape to Midian, a region where he could find safety.
Why did Moses choose Midian as his place of refuge?
Is there any historical or cultural reason he chose Midian?
Is there any significance to Moses choosing Midian?

A Matter of Geography!When a criminal flees, he usually takes the quickest and safest route for escaping! So notice the dilemma of Moses:

Moses could not flee southward. The "south" was along the Nile River settlements of the Egyptians. These reached all the way to Sudan (Cush), for hundreds of miles. Moses could have been apprehended anywhere along the way, before he reached the safety of Africa's wilderness, way to the south.
Moses could not flee "north" up the Palestinian coast because the route from the Delta of the Nile up to Palestine was dotted with Egyptian forts and military regiments! These forts protected Egypt's northern border. Moses would hesitate to venture north.
To the "west" was desert land. The major city of Cyrene was best reached by ship, because the desert route would be cumbersome and with hardship, unless Moses travel with a caravan. But that would not facilitate fleeing fast.
Heading "east" down and across the Sinai desert routes were best for fleeing, and especially ending up across the Gulf of Aqaba in a different country separated by the gulf. A land of isolated shepherds, instead of metropolises where news of Moses's murder would be communicated, would be ideal for hiding out.

The meeting of Jethro's daughters was happenstance---or rather Providential!---and the rest is history. It was in this solitude of desert residence and labor that Moses was able to hear the voice of God without the distractions of civilization and feckless culture.

+1. This seems very sound to me. A visual might improve the answer though.

We are not told why Moses chose Midian. It is quite possible that he originally intended to reach Canaan or the Transjordan since there may have been pockets of Israelite population there, as well as (certainly) descendants of Isaac (through Esau), Lot and Ishmael. In other words, he not have intended on Midian as his final destination but settled there because Zipporah's father invited him to remain. (Ex. 2:21)
Here are some possible factors as to why Moses went to Midian, whether or not it was his intended destination or only a route of escape wither relative few Egyptian agents:

Midian was populated by nomadic herdsmen. It thus provided good opportunities for Moses to disguise himself and blend in, compared to the settled agricultural cultures of the Nile Valley where Pharaoh's agents had good networks of local government, tax-collectors and spies.

God led him there because it was the location of Sinai, where God would appear to him and call him to lead the Exodus.

He was raised for several years by his mother, (Exodus 2:9-11) so he may have known who his ancestors were and where they came from. Midian was in the direction of the ancestral home of his people, who were descended from Abraham.

Midian was populated by tribes that had the same cultural roots as Israel. It takes its name from a son of Abraham and Keturah. Other tribes that lived there included the Moabites (descended from Lot) and Amalekites (descended from Esau).

As a priest of Midian, Jethro/Ruel recognized Yahweh as well as other gods. Yahweh was unknown by that name in Africa. Although Moses had not yet been called by God, he may have known enough of his origins to be aware that his people's God was worshiped by Midianites, even though not in a monotheistic manner.


These are some of the reasons Moses might have gone to Midian

+1. Well-structured and thought-out answer.

Moses should have no intention of choosing Midian. His primary focus was to escape from areas under Egyptian influence. To avoid Canaan, he move further southeast into the territory of the Midianites, a nomandic tribe actively present in that region.
God might have a plan for Moses as well. Moses' father-in-law, Jethro, is described as 'a priest' (Exodus 2:16; 3:1). Although the Midianites were polytheistic, as noted in Exodus 18:11, Jethro declared, "Now I know that the Lord is greater than all other gods". Jethro played a significant role in shaping Moses into a great leader during his 40 years of wandering.
Exodus 18:17-24 state:

17 Moses’ father-in-law replied, “What you are doing is not good. 18 You and these people who come to you will only wear yourselves out. The work is too heavy for you; you cannot handle it alone. 19 Listen now to me and I will give you some advice, and may God be with you. You must be the people’s representative before God and bring their disputes to him. 20 Teach them his decrees and instructions, and show them the way they are to live and how they are to behave. 21 But select capable men from all the people—men who fear God, trustworthy men who hate dishonest gain—and appoint them as officials over thousands, hundreds, fifties and tens. 22 Have them serve as judges for the people at all times, but have them bring every difficult case to you; the simple cases they can decide themselves. That will make your load lighter, because they will share it with you. 23 If you do this and God so commands, you will be able to stand the strain, and all these people will go home satisfied.”
24 Moses listened to his father-in-law and did everything he said. (NIV)

The Lord is known to be capable of choosing anyone as His vassal, righteous or wicked, to carry out His plan.

I figure that since Moses was educated it would make sense that there would be a reason for him fleeing to Midian. ray and Dan presented some compelling arguments.
